# Using remove() function in jquery shifts elements to the left. How to disable it?

Tags: jquery, shift

I want to remove elements from a table using jquery function: `remove()`, but without shifting the remaining elements to the left. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes. Do not remove the elements and set their visibility to `hidden` instead.

Comment: I need to remove them not to hide.